# setHideOnContentScrollEnabled not working for targeted API 21+ devices

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to modify my application to hide my ActionBar when the user scrolls. Currently, we aren't concerned with supporting this feature on pre-lollipop devices, but the code is primarily focused on pre-lollipop and has been slowly modified to accommodate API 21+ as needed.

I am using setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(true) to attempt to hide on scroll, and then having the hideoffset set, but nothing I do is seeming to work. My fragments come in onto the RecyclerView shown below in the base activity layout for Main.

I also have a ModuleActivity that extends MainActivity and imports android.app.ActionBar. I'm wondering if the issue could potentially be with the support library, but I would imagine that it would flag if that's the case.

**MainActivity**

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public abstract class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  .
  .
  .
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    }
    if (getContentResourceID() != 0) {
        setContentView(getContentResourceID());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mProgressIndicator = (SimpleAssetImageView) findViewById(R.id.progressIndicator);
    if (getActionBar() == null) {
        return;
    }
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getActionBar().setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHideOffset(1);
    }

}
```

**ModuleActivity.java**

```
...
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
...

public abstract class ModuleActivity extends MainActivity {


   .
   .
   .
   }
```

**mainactivity_baselayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<include layout="@layout/default_drawer_menu_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0"
        compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.19.0"
        compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0"
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'loader:1.9.4'
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set nestedScrollingEnabled true in XML file for your RecyclerView the code will working.